# Convergence of $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I had to prove that the integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(x^2)}}{x}dx$ converges. I thought splitting it to $$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x}dx+\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x}dx+\int_0^1\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x}dx+\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x}dx$$ and then to activative on the first and last dirichle test but I'm sure that $\int_a^bsinx^2$ is bounded... Furthermore what can be done with the integrals in the middle. Mupad claims the integral converges to 0. How can I apply convergence tests to these integrals?

Comment: If we let $f(0)=0$, the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x^2}{x}$ becomes continuous, hence $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ poses no problem. (Also, $f$ is an *odd* function, which explains the result $0$).

Comment: I can't let $f(0)=0$. About odd functions: It doesn't enough: take $g(x)=\frac 1 x$ which is also odd but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g\ne 0$ but $\infty$ since $\int_0^{\infty}gdx$ diverges.

Comment: *Why* can't you let $f(0)=0$? If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $\lim_{c\to b^-} \int_a^cf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{c\to a^+}\int_c^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx$, isn't it? Also, while  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$ indeed diverges, it is not correct to say that it is $\infty$. I didn't say that odd is enough, but meant that *if* you have convergence *then* the limit must be $0$.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1\sin(x^2)dx/x$ isn't an improper integral! We should note that whatever $f(0)$ is, $f(x)$ is integrable on $[-1,1]$ and the value doesn't change!

Comment: @Frank Define improper integral, please.

Comment: @FrankScience this $\int_{-1}^1$ is *formally* an improper integral, only by the existence of a continuous extension into $0$ it is essentially no longer improper.

Comment: @GitGud It's not explicated in wikipedia. However, on our textbook, it's said that (for simplicity, there's only one singularity) if $f$ is unbounded on $(a,b]$ and Riemann-integrable on $[a+\epsilon,b]$ for all $\epsilon>0$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen See my comment above.

Comment: @FrankScience As you refer to Wikipedia: They say  "Integrals are also improper if the integrand is undefined at an interior point of the domain of integration" This is the case here, so Coargu's doubts about $x=0$ are a priori justified.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Well, I see. It seems that such a definition is not quite important. The (essential) singularities are essentially related to unboundedness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should say something more: we can determine the value of the integral (from $0$ to $\infty$)!

It's easy, however, if we apply the substitution $x=\sqrt u$ where $u\ge 0$. Since $u=x^2$ is (strictly) monotone, the substitution is justified.

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x^2}xdx=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}udu=\frac\pi4$$

The last one is due to [Dirichlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral).

EDIT: We should note that there's something schematic:
$$\frac{f(x^m)}xdx=\alpha\frac{f(u)}udu$$
where $u=x^m$ and $\alpha$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, splitting it is a good idea.

According to the comments, by the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0} x\cdot\displaystyle\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2} = 0\cdot 1=0$, we can conclude that $\sin(x^2)/x$ can be made continuous, hence its integral must exist ocer the compact integral $[-1,1]$. (And, anyway it is $0$ because the function is odd.)

For the other two parts, consider the zeroes: $x=\pm\sqrt{k\pi},\ k\in\Bbb N$, and let 
$$A_k:=\int_{\sqrt{k\pi}}^{\sqrt{(k+1)\pi}} \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}dx$$
Then we have that the sequence $(A_k)$ is *alternating*, and as 
$$|A_k|\le \frac{\sqrt{(k+1)\pi}-\sqrt{k\pi}}{\sqrt{k\pi}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{k\pi}\cdot(\sqrt{(k+1)\pi}+\sqrt{k\pi})}\ \to 0$$
as $k\to\infty$, we have that $(A_k)$ is a *Leibniz* sequence, hence converges.

Answer (score 0):

The function 
$$
f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\ 
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x} & \text{ for } x \ne 0\\ 
0 & \text{ for } x=0\end{cases}
$$
is continuous and theorefore integrable on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

For every $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $-a,b>1$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_a^bf&=&\int_{-1}^1f+\int_a^{-1}f+\int_1^bf=\int_1^bf-\int_1^{-a}f=\int_{-a}^b f\\
&=&\frac12\int_{a^2}^{b^2}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx
=-\frac12\left[\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\right]_{a^2}^{b^2}-\int_{a^2}^{r^2}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx\\
&=&\frac12\left(\frac{\cos(b^2)}{b^2}-\frac{\cos(a^2)}{a^2}\right)-\int_{a^2}^{b^2}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx.
\end{eqnarray}
It follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
\left|\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\right|&\le& \frac{1}{2a^2}+\frac{1}{2b^2}+\int_{\min\{a^2,b^2\}}^{\max\{a^2,b^2\}}\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{2a^2}+\frac{1}{2b^2}-\frac{1}{3(\max\{a^2,b^2\})^6}+\frac{1}{3(\min\{a^2,b^2\})^6},
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$
\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\right|=\lim_{a\to -\infty}\lim_{b\to \infty}\left|\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right|=0,
$$
i.e.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f=0.
$$