# Test for divergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx$ without evaluating the integral

Tags: improper-integrals

I would like to prove that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx$$ diverges without actually evaluating the integral. Is there a convergence test from calculus or real analysis that can show that this integral diverges?

Thanks.

Edit: Someone pointed out that this is a possible duplicate. However, the question put forth as a possible duplicate asks about $\sin(x^2)$, not about $\sin^2(x)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{x^2}}{x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437383/convergence-of-int-limits-infty-infty-frac-sinx2xdx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a divergent integral by [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma), since $\sin^2(x)$ is a non-negative function with mean value $\frac{1}{2}$. In more explicit terms, by integration by parts we have

$$ \int_{\pi}^{N\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\,dx =\color{blue}{\left[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sin(2x)}{4x}\right]_{\pi}^{N\pi}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi}^{N\pi}\frac{dx}{x}}+\color{blue}{O(1)} $$
where the blue terms are bounded, but the red term equals $\frac{1}{2}\log N$.

Comment: I don't understand why you choose $\pi$ and $N\pi$ as the limits of integration.

Comment: @Taliant: aesthetics only, but any other choice equally does the job.

Comment: So let's say $N\pi = \infty$. Can we conclude from that that the integral in red diverges, and so $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}$ diverges?

Comment: @Taliant: the red integral is unbounded as $N\to +\infty$, hence $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\,dx = +\infty$.

Answer (score 9):

We see  there is no problem around $0$ so the problem lies in the convergence of:
\begin{align} 
\int^\infty_M \frac{\sin^2(x)} {x} dx
\end{align} 
For $M>0$, let's take it very large (you'll see the reason in the next line).

We prove that it diverges by a (badass) **contradiction**. Assume it converges. Then we know that:
\begin{align} 
\int^\infty_{M} \frac{\sin^2(x+\pi/2)}{x+\pi/2}dx 
\end{align} 
converges too. Hence by comparison the following converges too:
\begin{align} 
\int^\infty_{M} \frac{\sin^2(x+\pi/2)}{x}dx = 
\int^\infty_{M} \frac{\cos^2(x)}{x}dx 
\end{align} 
But then we get that the next one is also convergent since sum of convergent integrals is convergent:
\begin{align} 
\int^\infty_{M} \frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) }{x}dx =\int^\infty_M\frac{1}{x} dx
\end{align} 
I think this is a *beautiful* contradiction. Hence the integral that we was considering was not convergent in the first place.

Comment: Very clever trick !

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\ge\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k\pi}\int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}\sin^2(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2k}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Integrate from $x=n\pi$ to $x=(n+1)\pi$.  With the squared sine being nonnegative the integrand is greater than $(\sin^2x)/((n+1)\pi)$.  Conclude that the definite integral from $x=n\pi$ to $x=(n+1)\pi$ is greater than $\pi/(2(n+1))$ and then compare the full integral from $x=0$ to $x=\infty$ to the harmonic series.